# How to detect no collision in a sprite kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm doing a game where you have to capture candies using a spider hung by a thread, as I show in this link: [Game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TntKa.jpg) (I'm new here so I can't post images yet). I already have the movement of the spider from left to right and also I'm able to catch the candies using SKAction moving through 'Y', my only issue is I didn't figure it out yet how to know if the spider don't capture any candy, during his movement, I was trying use the allContactedBodies function when the action finish but the count of the array returned is always zero. Any suggestions?

Here is the code :

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    private var rope = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rope")
    private var anchor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "anchor")
    private var currentCharacter: SKSpriteNode!
    private var candy: SKSpriteNode!
    var direction : String = "backward"

    var lastCandyAdded: TimeInterval = 0
    let candyVelocity: CGFloat = 4.0

    let characterBitMask  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let candyBitMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

    let characterVelocity: CGFloat = 18.0
    var direction : String = "backward"

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.addAnchor()
        self.addRope()
        self.addCharacter()

        let jointOneFixed = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: anchor.physicsBody!, bodyB: rope.physicsBody!, anchor: anchor.position)
        self.physicsWorld.add(jointOneFixed);

        let jointTwoFixed = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: rope.physicsBody!, bodyB: currentCharacter.physicsBody!, anchor: currentCharacter.position)
        self.physicsWorld.add(jointTwoFixed);
    }

    func addAnchor(){
        anchor.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height + 1)
        anchor.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        anchor.setScale(1)
        anchor.zPosition = 2
        anchor.name = "anchor"
        anchor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: anchor.size.width, height: anchor.size.height))
        anchor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        anchor.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
        anchor.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0;
        anchor.physicsBody?.mass = 10;
        self.addChild(anchor)
    }

    func addCharacter() {
        let characterName: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "current_character")!
        currentCharacter = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: characterName);
        currentCharacter.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height - 400)
        currentCharacter.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        currentCharacter.setScale(0.43)
        currentCharacter.zPosition = 2
        currentCharacter.name = "character"
        currentCharacter.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: currentCharacter.size)
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = characterBitMask
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = candyBitMask
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = candyBitMask;
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0;
        currentCharacter.physicsBody?.mass = 20;
        self.addChild(currentCharacter)
    }

    func addRope() {
        rope.position = CGPoint(x: anchor.position.x, y: anchor.position.y - 70)
        rope.setScale(0.65)
        rope.zPosition = 1
        rope.name = "rope"
        rope.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: rope.size.width, height: rope.size.height))
        rope.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
        rope.physicsBody?.friction = 0;
        rope.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0;
        rope.physicsBody?.mass = 5;
        rope.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.addChild(rope)
    }

    func addCandy() {
        let number = Int.random(min: 1, max: 24)
        let candyWord = "candie"
        let candyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(candyWord)\(number)")
        candy = SKSpriteNode(texture: candyTexture)
        candy.zPosition = 3
        candy.setScale(0.40)
        candy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: max(candy.size.width / 2, candy.size.height / 2))
        candy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        candy.name = "candy"
        candy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = candyBitMask
        candy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = characterBitMask
        candy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = characterBitMask
        candy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        candy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 20, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + 150)
        self.addChild(candy)
    }

    func moveCandy() {
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "candy", using: {(node, stop) -> Void in
            if let candy = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                candy.position = CGPoint(x: candy.position.x - self.candyVelocity, y: candy.position.y)
                if candy.position.x < 0 {
                    candy.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        self.moveCandy()
        self.moveCharacter()
        if currentTime - self.lastCandyAdded >  0.75 {
            self.lastCandyAdded = currentTime + Double.random(min: 0.00, max: 0.60)
            self.addCandy()
        }
    }

    func collisionBetween(candy: SKNode, object: SKNode) {
        let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 100, duration:0.0)
        let shrinkRope = SKAction.animate(with: [SKTexture(imageNamed: "rope")], timePerFrame: 0)

        let moveUpBlock = SKAction.run({
            self.anchor.run(moveUp)
        })
        let shrinkRopeBlock = SKAction.run({
            self.rope.run(shrinkRope)
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.07), shrinkRopeBlock, moveUpBlock])
        self.run(sequence)

        candy.removeFromParent()
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node else { return }
        guard let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else { return }

        if nodeA.name == "candy" && nodeB.name == "character" {
            collisionBetween(candy: nodeA, object: nodeB)
        } else if nodeA.name == "character" && nodeB.name == "candy" {
            collisionBetween(candy: nodeB, object: nodeA)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -100, duration:0.0)
        let stretchRope = SKAction.animate(with: [SKTexture(imageNamed: "rope_stretch")], timePerFrame: 0)

        let moveDownBlock = SKAction.run({
            self.anchor.run(moveDown, completion: {
               var physicBodies = self.currentCharacter.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies();

                // This count is always zero
                print(physicBodies?.count)

            })
        })
        let stretchRopeBlock = SKAction.run({
            self.rope.run(stretchRope)
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDownBlock, stretchRopeBlock])
        self.run(sequence)
    }

    func moveCharacter(){
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "anchor", using: {(node, stop) -> Void in
            if let anchorNode = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                if anchorNode.position.x < 120 {
                    anchorNode.position = CGPoint(x: anchorNode.position.x + self.characterVelocity, y: anchorNode.position.y)
                    self.direction = "forward"
                } else if anchorNode.position.x > self.size.width - 120 {
                    anchorNode.position = CGPoint(x: anchorNode.position.x - self.characterVelocity, y: anchorNode.position.y)
                    self.direction = "backward"
                } else if self.direction == "forward" {
                    anchorNode.position = CGPoint(x: anchorNode.position.x + self.characterVelocity, y: anchorNode.position.y)
                    self.direction = "forward"
                } else {
                    anchorNode.position = CGPoint(x: anchorNode.position.x - self.characterVelocity, y: anchorNode.position.y)
                    self.direction = "backward"
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a lot of code in this question...too much, it makes it hard to focus on what is really happening. You are also missing a block of code for moveCharacter().

You should strongly look at creating subclasses for your player, rope and (mostly)candies. I would also look into creating an array of candies initially so that you are not dynamically creating physics objects during run time.

As for your question wouldn't it be as simple as creating a couple of variables in your class

```
private var isMoving = false
private var didGetCandy = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //prevent the user from firing the move while in the middle of a move
    guard !isMoving else { return }
    isMoving = true

    let moveDownBlock = SKAction.run({
        self.anchor.run(moveDown) {
           //this is an appreviated form of a 'completion' block
           self.isMoving = false
           print("did I get a candy \(didGetCandy)")
        }
    })
}

func collisionBetween(candy: SKNode, object: SKNode) {
    didGetCandy = true
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ron Myschuk, thanks for the advices I'm going to create the classes for the character, rope and candies and also create an array of candies to avoid creating physics objects during run time. But the solution you gave me does not  work, the issue is the action completion is triggered before the collisionBetween function, so even If I get a candy the variable "isMoving" is still in false

Comment: did you mean "didGetCandy" is still false?

Comment: can you give some insight into how the player moves? I am assuming the spider moves up & down? I don't see any code here which moves the spider back up. can you add the code for moveCharacter to your question ?

Comment: Yes, "didGetCandy" is false. Sorry

Comment: I already added the moveCharacter() function, but this function just move the character from left to right, the up and down movement is triggered by touching the screen.

Comment: there is no code in the touchesBegan that indicate that the spider moves back up

Comment: The spyder moves back up in the function collisionBetween(candy: SKNode) if the spider gets a candy

Comment: what happens if he doesn't get the candy? how would the spider move back up

Comment: you need to supply some info on how you want the game to function, what happens if the spider gets a candy, what happens when a spider doesn't get a candy? is the move down and up after a single tap? or does move down happen after 1 tap and you want the spider to move up after another tap? a non collision is constantly happening so you are better off to check for collisions vs. non collisions

Comment: If the spider doesn't a get a candy, the game is over, that's why the spider just moves back up if capture a candy